# TYPO3 Call to a member function on a non-object not fixed by clearing cache

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, extbase

IM trying to inject a repository into one of my controllers and i get this error:

Call to a member function findByChar() on a non-object

I seached the internet but all i could find is "delete the cache"

I did that a hundred times alredy but i just can't get it to work.
Are there any other approaches i didn't find?

(typo v 6.2.6) Injection:

```
    /**
     * streetRepository
     *
     * @var \Omg\CollectionPlan\Domain\Repository\StreetRepository
     * @inject
     */
     protected $streetRepository;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also debug the ClassLoader with XDebug and see if the ClassLoader is loading the repository class source file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't clear the right cache.

In Development context, you have the button "Flush system caches" in the clear cache menu.

If you are not in Development context, you can do the same in the install tool ("Important actions" --> "Clear all cache").

If you cannot switch to Development context and nevertheless want to activate the "Flush system caches" button, add this to the User TSconfig:

```
options.clearCache.system = 1
```